# Vagrant up on a box, not recognizing provider

Tags: vagrant

This is my first time uploading a package.box to Vagrant.  I'm testing a `vagrant up` and get the following:

```
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: myprivateaccount/throwaway1
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/myprivateaccount/throwaway1
Requested provider: [:virtualbox]
```

However, `virtualbox` IS what I have installed (version 6.0.12) successfully running Ubuntu boxes.  Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, in my case the issue was this:

```
If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
```

released.

Once I "released" the box, it worked.  I don't know if the provider (vmware, virtualbox, etc.) is the issue at all.

Comment: Ah yes of course, "release" the box. Would a small backyard do or does it need a larger pasture? Am I holding a lock of some kind? ***What does "release" even mean?*** (After some googling it turns out that this means the box needs to be given a version and... maybe published somehow? It's using "release" in the sense of "release the next version of your software". This was rather non-obvious, but even with that out of the way, it's still not obvious what to do, and "vagrant release box" isn't exactly unambiguous in a web search.)

Comment: I'm not going to -1 despite the frustration (in fact I just +1'ed this, because thank you for following up at all and leaving the main big-picture hint about releasing the box being the thing) but I just want to point out that *you were already **there***! when you wrote this answer you knew the command you ran, you knew what documentation you read, and what could've been a quick copy-paste for you once is now and indefinitely-scoped excursion for anyone else who needs this answer.